# Sourcing the same shell script file everytime

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I just had a quick question regarding sourcing files in shell script.

I have created a shell script file that has a function which I can execute. However, everytime I restart my terminal and run the command in my shell I have to run `source ~/path/to/shell/file` everytime before running my function.

Is there any permanent fix for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the shell startup files are for. If you're using bash, any commands you place in the file `.bashrc` in your home directory (`$HOME/.bashrc`) will be executed every time you start a new shell (the name is short for "bash run commands"). So either copy the file with your function definition into the `.bashrc` or just add the `source` command to it, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi, I have opened the  `.bashrc` file but I don't know what you mean by add the definition to the file.

Comment: Whatever is in `~/path/to/shell/file`, just copy it and paste it into `~/.bashrc`.  OR, put a line in the .bashrc containing just `source ~/path/to/shell/file`.  Your choice.